# About probability of arranging books on a shelf

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Lets suppose that we have 4 math books, 6 statistics books, and 10 books of other subjects, and we want to order a shelf with those books. The restriction we have is that the math and the statistic ones must be together in the shelf (I mean, the math ones should be together, and next to the statistics books). So the question is:

What is the probability about this event happens?

**Remark:** Every book is different

Comment: Just to clarify: Denoting M=math book and S=statistics and O=other book, would something like
$$
OOOOOSMSMSMSSMSOOOOO
$$
be permitted? Or only
$$
OOOOOMMMMSSSSSSOOOOO
$$
?

Comment: Only like your second arrange is allowed

Comment: Okay, then I would consider all the math books as "one box of math books" and all the statistics books as "one box of statistics books". They need to be next to each other in the "math-statistics box". Now the problem should become easier...

Comment: Are math books books identical or different ?? Same question for statistics books ??

Comment: The books are different, so the order should takes relevance

Comment: Are the books of other subjects different or the same (like math or statistics books)?

Comment: All the books are different. There is no similar books in this problem

Comment: Are math and stastics books different too?

Comment: Yes, the books are all different.

Comment: If so then the answer is $$2\cdot4!\cdot6!\cdot10!$$

Comment: Ok, I get it, but why is there a 10! ? I mean, if we take the statistics and math books, and we put it together in a "box", we would have 11 elements, or it doesn't?

Comment: I mean all the books are different and the math books must be next to the statistics books like this: mmmmssssss or ssssssmmmm              where every m and s are different.

Comment: But with 10! you count invalid cases like mmmsmsssss, dont you?

Comment: $10!$ is the permutation of the books of other subjects

Comment: I now think over this problem and the answer is even bigger.

Comment: I got the answer: $$2\cdot11\cdot10!\cdot4!\cdot6!$$

Comment: Is it all right?

Comment: You ask about a probability without introducing a distribution. Did you intend to imply that that the books are arranged randomly with all configurations being equally likely? If so, what is the relevance of the remark "Every book is different"?